# How to fix Kotlin Reactjs tutorial error: listen EADDRINUSE

Tags: node.js, reactjs, kotlin

As part of this [basic tutorial](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Building%20Web%20Applications%20with%20React%20and%20Kotlin%20JS/01_Introduction), I downloaded the code from [this repo](https://github.com/kotlin-hands-on/web-app-react-kotlin-js-gradle), and attempted to run it with the command `./gradlew run` on an Ubuntu 20.04 environment.
This resulted in the following error:

```
> Task :browserDevelopmentRun
✖ ｢wds｣:  Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:8080
✖ ｢wds｣:  Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:8080
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1318:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1503:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:69:8) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -98,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8080
}
```

The process seems to be the only one running on this port, and attempts to get rid of any other processes using port 8080 (`sudo kill -9 'sudo lsof -t -i:8080'`, `killall node`, etc...) have no effect. The conflicting processes seem to both come from within the tutorial web app.

Changing the port using a .env file also did not work. No matter what port is set (8081, 3000, 83000, etc...), there is still the error of port 8080 already being in use.

Does anyone know a solution to this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Check whether any services are running in background . (Windows service). Run command netstat -plnt (in Linux case). Try to change the port in your application. Ex. to 8081

Comment: Check whether any services are running in background . (Windows service). Run command netstat -plnt (in Linux case). Try to change the port in your application. Ex. to 8081

Comment: I updated the post to specifically state that changing the port did not work. The conflicting processes fighting over port 8080 appear to be within the app itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So while I didn't figure out exactly which dependency was causing this issue, on trying out a couple of the pull request on the repository, I found that this one: https://github.com/kotlin-hands-on/web-app-react-kotlin-js-gradle/pull/11 fixes the problem. Hopefully, it will be merged into the main branch soon!